# Replacing fragments dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to switch a fragment when a button is pressed inside fragment itself and if an error is thrown by new fragment it will change back to the first fragment. I followed other answer, but none worked, what I get is always a blank fragment.

My main activity is a `AppCompatActivity`. This is a part of `onCreate()`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    FragmentAdapter pageAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), MainActivity.this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
}
```

In main acivity I've this function to switch fragment

```
public void switchFragment(){
    Fragment fragment = null;
    try {
        fragment = SecondFragment.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.viewpager, fragment).commit();
}
```

And inside FirstFragment class:

```
((MainActivity) activityReference.get().getActivity()).switchFragment();
```

On startup the first fragmet is active and works well, when I press the button that call `switchFragment()` it become white. What did I miss?

Comment: I found a solution. I created a root fragment with a FrameLayout and now I'm able to use correctly beginTransaction().replace()

Answer (score 0):

To change the fragment in your view pager, you can simply call currentItem method on viewpager. For e.g

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I wrote a "wrong" title. I've 4 fragment alredy setted in viewPager, what I need is to replace the fragment

Comment: just to be sure, you need to change it for a viewPager only. right?

Comment: yeah. I've the same activity, with this viewPager. Inside this viewPager I've 4 fragment. 3 of them will be always the same and never changes. One of them need to be replaced when the button is pressed inside it. I get a white fragment. What can I see inside log console is that the fragmetn is correctly created but it is not attached to the viewPager for some reason!

Answer (score -1):

From your code your `fragment = SecondFragment.newInstance();` line could be throwing an error in which case the fragment will be `null` when it reaches `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.viewpager, fragment).commit();`, that could be causing you get a blank fragment.

Just making a null check before setting the fragment will ensure your first fragment remains visible in the case an error occurs:

`if (fragment != null) 
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.viewpager, fragment).commit();`

Comment: No, is not a problem of nullPointer. Even with null checking it gives me white screen